# Why Akatsuki Kojou almost always use Regulus Aurum familiar for attacking?

Tags: strike-the-blood

Akatsuki Kojou has 12 familiars. All of them werent available at first and he started to unlock them one by one, and even though Regulus Aurum was the first familiar he unlocked, he uses it once and again much more than the other familiars he unlocked later. Why is this so? Is it more handy, is it specially powerful or what?

Comment: IIRC some of the later ones were rather specific in their use. Regulus Aurum is the hammer to everyone's nail.